# Updatepanels not working after loading records from DB to tinymce editor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, tinymce, updatepanel

I am developing website by using ASP.NET. In there I use a tinymce text editor to a textbox to decorate the user input.

Here is the code.

```
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.2/tinymce.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        resize: true,
        mode: "specific_textareas",
        editor_selector: "tinymceDescription",
        encoding: "xml",
        theme: "modern",
        plugins: [
         "advlist lists link preview",
         "searchreplace",
         "directionality"
        ],
        toolbar1: "bold italic underline | bullist numlist outdent indent | link | preview",
        menubar: false,
        statusbar: true,


        setup: function (editor) {
            editor.on('SaveContent', function (ed) {
                ed.content = ed.content.replace(/&#39/g, "&apos");
            });
        }


    });
```

To applly it to text box I use this.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Width="100%" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="15" AutoComplete="off" ClientIDMode="Static" MaxLength="6000" class="tinymceDescription"></asp:TextBox><br />
```

Then to save the content of this text box I use this in save method.

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(txtDescription.Text)
```

So this is working fine. When retrive from the DB it shows correctly. But the probelem is when I load the registered data from the DB to this tinymce textbox the whole page's update panels not working.

Here is the code that use to retrive data

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
     dt = objBLL.Get_ToEdit(Id: selectedId);
                txtDescription.Text = dt.Rows[0]["description"].ToString();
```

Whats the wrong?

Comment: Could do with seeing the structure of your UpdatePanel. And have you checked for errors in the console? Could be your HTML for tinyMCE is bleeding out and causing errors.

Comment: @Hugo Yates How to check the errors in the console? Code doesnt have errors and design page doesnt have errors.

Comment: Press F12 in the browser, you'll be able to see if there are any JavaScript errors occuring